# WordPress Shortcode and Dynamic CSS

Tags: php, shortcode, css, html

I have a question I would like to ask to the WordPress developers,
Usually when creating a shortcode that need to generate custom css how do you proceed?

For example a simple button shortcode with the following options :

- text
- link
- text color
- background color
- **hover text color**
- **hover background color**

The problem is the hover color option, I would like to generate it dynamically directly to a css file without having to put any custom css in the head or inline `<style></style>`
block in the page.

The shortcode need of course to work when used several time in the same page.

I am thinking about using  wp_add_inline_style or wp_filesystem.

The main goal of this question is to create a shortcode with custom css added in a dynamic css file or a way to not add custom css directly in the page but to stil be able to add hover attribute.

If possible I would like to achieve this with only php html and css but if there is no solution I am also thinking to use javascript.

Any advice would be awesome.

Regards

Comment: `wp_add_inline_style()` would be my choice in most cases. Why the `hover` option is the problem and not the other?

Comment: As @cybmeta says, there should be no problem with hover states if you write css statements to a virtual file and add it dynamically. If you want to use inline style statements like `<a style="color:red;">` there is a trick to enable hover states on that and still validate your page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact using wp_add_inline_style would be the last option cause it still write css in the head of the page, also maybe I am not using it like I should but I am getting an error when generating two buttons in the same page.

Comment: So you want to use inline styles? What error are you getting on the buttons?

Comment: If possible I want to avoid inline styles on the page and put everything in css file dynamically, but I can't find a good way to do this, if this is not possible I would like to be able to put all the css in the head in 1 style block even if the shortcode is used "n" times.


The problem I got with `wp_add_inline_style()` is a fatal error that tell me I can't redeclare my function that creates the inline style.

Comment: Right. But by the time WP gets to evaluating the shortcode (assuming it is in a post) it already has generated the head of your page. You can't add styleblocks in the head anymore by that time, nor use `wp_add_inline_style`. Your plugin would have to become active while the head is still being generated and look forward to the post content from there. Within the WP shortcode system the approach @Rarst gives in his answer is best, except if you want your page to validate. In that case you shouldn't use `<style></style>` blocks, but put everything inline.

Comment: There is definitely a way to put `<style>` block in the head, a lot of plugin do this for example the visual composer, for each row there is custom css generated and put in the head.
If there is no way to have all the shortcode generated css in css file then I am opting for something similar.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to change the head of a page after it has been generated, you will have to do that at the user end with javascript. Like this: http://blog.masgum.net/loading-styles-inside-a-wordpress-shortcode/

Answer (score 3):

The closest to a reference technique in core would be `[gallery]` shortcode.

If you look at the source of implementing [`gallery_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/) function you'll see that it:

1. Generates instance number (so multiple shortcodes can be distinguished).
2. Outputs dynamic CSS inline into a page source, for each instance.

I wouldn't consider it particularly *neat* solution, but it is about as close as it gets within constraints of WP shortcodes architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

I was doing something similar before but I ended with too much dynamic css in the page.

That's why I am try to find a way to generate the css in a css file if possible and not directly in the page or at least in the head in only one `<style>` block.

Regards

Comment: Generating dynamic CSS as separate HTTP request would be horrible on server load. You can certainly try to adjust technique to output CSS in the head, but many third party shortcodes break if post content is processed early.